# Why this property of the integral doesn't work in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let $\operatorname{Reg}([a,b])$ denote the set of regulated functions on $[a,b]$ and suppose $c,d\in [a,b]$ with $c<d$. Let $f\in \operatorname{Reg}([a,b])$ be given, I want to show that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{c+\epsilon}^{d-\epsilon}f(x)dx=\int_c^d f(x)dx.$$

For that I've tried the following: using the triangle inequality we have

$$\left|\int_{c+\epsilon}^{d-\epsilon}f(x)dx-\int_c^df(x)dx\right|\leq\left|\int_{c+\epsilon}^{d-\epsilon}f(x)dx\right|+\left|\int_c^df(x)dx.\right|,$$

but we know that a property of the integral of regulated functions is:

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx\right|\leq (b-a)M,\qquad M = \sup\{|f(x)| : x\in[a,b]\}, \quad \forall \ f\in \operatorname{Reg}([a,b]).$$

Thus we should have:

$$\left|\int_{c+\epsilon}^{d-\epsilon}f(x)dx-\int_c^df(x)dx\right|\leq (d-c-2\epsilon)M_1+(d-c)M_2.$$

Where $M_1 = \sup\{|f(x)| : x\in (c+\epsilon,d-\epsilon)\}$ and $M_2 = \sup\{|f(x)| : x\in (c,d)\}$. But we have that $(c,d),(c+\epsilon,d-\epsilon)\subset [a,b]$ so that if $M = \sup\{|f(x)| : x\in [a,b]\}$ we certainly have $M_1,M_2\leq M$.

This gives

$$\left|\int_{c+\epsilon}^{d-\epsilon}f(x)dx-\int_c^df(x)dx\right|\leq (d-c-2\epsilon)M+(d-c)M = -2\epsilon M.$$

This is clearly wrong. If $\epsilon > 0$ and $M > 0$ this is saying that an absolute value is less than a negative number. So some step I took is not allowed, but I can't figure it out.

What am I missing here? And what is the right way to do this?

By the way, the definition of integral here is: the integral of a regulated function is defined by picking a sequence $(\phi_n)$ of step functions which converges uniformly to the regulated functions and defining $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b\phi_n(x)dx$.